# How do you keep content from your previous web page after clicking a link?

Tags: javascript, html, web

I'm sorry if this is a newbie question but I don't really know what to search for either.  How do you keep content from a previous page when navigating through a web site? For example, the right side Activity/Chat bar on facebook.  It doesn't appear to refresh when going to different profiles; it's not an iframe and doesn't appear to be ajax (I could be wrong).

Thanks,

Answer (score 4):

I believe what you're seeing in Facebook is not actual "page loads", but clever use of AJAX or [AHAH](http://microformats.org/wiki/rest/ahah).

So ... imagine you've got a web page.  It contains links.  Each of those links has a "hook" -- a chunk of JavaScript that gets executed when the link gets clicked.

If your browser doesn't support JavaScript, the link works as it normally would on an old-fashioned page, and loads another page.

But if JavaScript is turned on, then instead of navigating to an HREF, the code run by the hook causes a request to be placed to a different URL that spits out just the HTML that should be used to replace a DIV that's already showing somewhere on the page.

There's still a real link in the HTML just in case JS doesn't work, so the HTML you're seeing looks as it should.  Try disabling JavaScript in your browser and see how Facebook works.

Live updates like this are all over the place in Web 2.0 applications, from Facebook to Google Docs to Workflowy to Basecamp, etc.  The "better" tools provide the underlying HTML links where possible so that users without JavaScript can still get full use of the applications.  (This is called [Progressive Enhancement or Graceful degradation](https://ux.stackexchange.com/q/935), depending on your perspective.)  Of course, nobody would expect Google Docs to work without JavaScript.

Comment: Ohhh, ya, THAT's what he meant with this question.

Comment: +1 for AHAH, didn't know that's what it was being called. I lol'd. Thanks, fish.

Answer (score 2):

In the case of a chat like Facebook, you must save the entire conversation on the server side (for example in a database). Then, when the user changes the page, you can restore the state of the conversation on the server side (with PHP) or by querying your server like you do for the chat (Javascript + AJAX).

Answer (score 0):

This isn't done in Javascript.  It needs to be done using your back-end scripting language.

In PHP, for example, you use [Sessions](https://www.php.net/manual/en/intro.session.php).  The variables set by server-side scripts can be maintained on the server and tied together (between multiple requests/hits) using a cookie.

Comment: I think he's asking how the side part stays put during page navigation, as if it were a separate frame. The answer he's looking for will probably involve [manipulating the browser history](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/Manipulating_the_browser_history).

Answer (score 0):

One really helpful trick is to run [HTTPFox](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/httpfox/) in Firefox so you can actually monitor what's happening as you browse from one page to the next.  You can check out the POST/Cookies/Response tabs and watch for which web methods are being called by the AJAX-like behaviors on the page.  In doing this you can generally deduce how data is flowing to and from the pages, even though you don't have access to the server side code per se.

As for the answer to your specific question, there are too many approaches to list (cookies, server side persistence such as session or database writes, a simple form POST, VIEWSTATE in .net, etc..)

Answer (score -3):

You can open your last closed web-page by pressing **ctrl+shift+T** . Now you can save content as you like. Example: if i closed a web-page related by **[document sharing](http://fileshareplus.com/)** and now i am on travel web page. Then i press ctrl+shift+T. Now automatic my last web-page will open.  This function works on Mozilla, e explorer, opera and more. Hope this answer is helpful to you.

Comment: I believe this is not what the user was asking for.